# CSS / On hover, can I change the same element's ::after?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, styles, dropdown

I have  tag with class="dropdown-button" and want to style its ::after on first LI element hover.

I am trying this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-button">
   <li> home </li>
   <li> about us </li>
</ul>

style {

   .dropdown-button {
     margin-top:10px;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
    }  

  .dropdown-button::after {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
   }

   // To solve problem, I do this :
   .dropdown-button li:first-child:hover .dropdown-button::after{
     border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a2a3;
     content: "";
    }

    //But this doesn't work.

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can Add `li:hover::after(content:"test")`it's simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in js:

```
var el = $('.dropdown-button');
var firstChild = el.children().first();

firstChild.on('mouseover', onMouseOver);
firstChild.on('mouseout', onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver() {
    el.addClass('first-child-hovered');
}

function onMouseOut() {
    el.removeClass('first-child-hovered');
}
```

And then in css:

```
.first-child-hovered::after {
    // change style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :

```
.dropdown-button li:first-child:hover::after{
     border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a2a3;
     content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the deep answer is: affecting a parent's pseudo-class through a child's pseudo-class cannot be done by pure CSS. It's in the name: Cascading Style Sheets only supports styling in cascading direction, not upwards to its parent.
So here's a better fix. Introduce a new span element in your

, give it the :after pseudo-element properties and on hover of the list-item's first-child, display your new element. Solution all in CSS.
Please follow the snippet below:

```css
    .dropdown-button {
         margin-top:10px;
         border:1px solid #ccc;
         position: relative;
        }  
    
      .dropdown-button:after {
        border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        left: 7px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 0;
       }
    
      .dropdown-button1:after {
        
        border-bottom: 6px solid red;
        border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        content: "";
        display: none;
        left: 7px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        z-index: 3;
       }
       li:first-child:hover ~ .dropdown-button1:after {
         border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a2a3;
         display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="dropdown-button">
       <li> home </li>
       <li> about us </li>
       <span class="dropdown-button1"></span>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using jQuery

```
$(".dropdown-button").first('li').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
})

//CSS
.hovered:after {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a2a3;
   content: "";
}
```